# Coding And Binary Tree implementation C++

Tags: c++, tree

When searching for information about the Binary Tree, the code on people's blogs are complicated, so here I'm trying to code a very simple Binary Tree.

Am I missing anything? Is there a better way I could be implementing the BinTree::Remove?

```
#ifndef _BINTREE_H__
#define _BINTREE_H__
using namespace std;

class BinTree{
private:
    struct tree_node 
    {
        tree_node* left;
        tree_node* right;
        int data;
    };
    tree_node* root;
public:
    BinTree()
    {
        root = NULL; //Don't forget The constructor!It's Gonna kill the code
    }
    void Insert(int);
    //int nodes();
    bool IsEmpty(){ return root == NULL; }
    void print_Preorder();
    void Preorder(tree_node *);
    bool Search(int);
    void Remove(int);
};

void BinTree::Insert(int d){
    tree_node * t = new tree_node;
    tree_node * parent = NULL;
    t->data = d;
    t->left = NULL;
    t->right = NULL;

    if (IsEmpty()){
        root = t;
    }

    else{
        tree_node * curr;
        curr = root;
        while (curr){
            parent = curr;  
            if (t->data > curr->data) curr = curr->right;
            else curr = curr->left;
        }
        if (parent->data > t->data)
            parent->left = t;
        else
            parent->right = t;
    }
}

void BinTree::print_Preorder()
{
    Preorder(root);
}

void BinTree::Preorder(tree_node* p)
{
    if (p != NULL)
    {

        cout << " " << p->data << " ";
        if (p->left) Preorder(p->left);
        if (p->right) Preorder(p->right);
    }
    else return;
}


bool BinTree::Search(int d)
{
    bool found = false;
    if (IsEmpty())
    {
        cout << " This Tree is empty! " << endl;
        return false;
    }
    tree_node* curr;
    tree_node* parent;
    curr = root;
    parent = (tree_node*)NULL;
    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        if (curr->data == d)
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            parent = curr;
            if (d>curr->data) curr = curr->right;
            else curr = curr->left;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
    {
        cout << " Data not found! " << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " Data found! " << endl;
    }

    return found;
}



void BinTree::Remove(int d)
{
    bool found = false;
    if (IsEmpty())
    {
        cout << " This Tree is empty! " << endl;
        return;
    }
    tree_node* curr;
    tree_node* parent;
    curr = root;
    parent = NULL;
    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        if (curr->data == d)
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            parent = curr;
            if (d>curr->data) curr = curr->right;//l
            else curr = curr->left;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
    {
        cout << " Data not found! " << endl;
        return;
    }

    // Node with single child
    if ((curr->left == NULL && curr->right != NULL) || (curr->left != NULL
        && curr->right == NULL))
    {
        if (curr->left == NULL && curr->right != NULL)
        {
            if (parent->left == curr)
            {
                parent->left = curr->right;
                delete curr;
            }
            else
            {
                parent->right = curr->right;
                delete curr;
            }
        }
        else // left child present, no right child
        {
            if (parent->left == curr)
            {
                parent->left = curr->left;
                delete curr;
            }
            else
            {
                parent->right = curr->left;
                delete curr;
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    //We're looking at a leaf node
    if (curr->left == NULL && curr->right == NULL)
    {
        if (parent == NULL)
        {
            delete curr;

        }
        else
        if (parent->left == curr) parent->left = NULL;
        else parent->right = NULL;
        delete curr;
        return;
    }


    //Node with 2 children
    // replace node with smallest value in right subtree
    if (curr->left != NULL && curr->right != NULL)
    {
        tree_node* chkr;
        chkr = curr->right;
        if ((chkr->left == NULL) && (chkr->right == NULL))
        {
            curr = chkr;
            delete chkr;
            curr->right = NULL;
        }
        else // right child has children
        {
            //if the node's right child has a left child
            // Move all the way down left to locate smallest element

            if ((curr->right)->left != NULL)
            {
                tree_node* lcurr;
                tree_node* lcurrp;
                lcurrp = curr->right;
                lcurr = (curr->right)->left;
                while (lcurr->left != NULL)
                {
                    lcurrp = lcurr;
                    lcurr = lcurr->left;
                }
                curr->data = lcurr->data;
                delete lcurr;
                lcurrp->left = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                tree_node* tmp;
                tmp = curr->right;
                curr->data = tmp->data;
                curr->right = tmp->right;
                delete tmp;
            }

        }
        return;
    }

}
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you can use C++11, otherwise some of the points don't apply.

1. Don't put `using namespace std;` into a header, because everyone using your tree now also has the whole standard library in their namespace.
2. Put the public parts above the private parts. People are only interested in what they can actually use, not the implementation details.
3. `Preorder` should be `private` since it cannot be used in a meaningful way anyways.
4. Don't use `NULL`, use `nullptr` instead. `NULL` is just a macro for `0` (in theory it could be something else, but in practice it never is). Nonsensical things like `int i = NULL;` and `int *p; p + NULL;` compile even though they are clearly errors. `nullptr` doesn't have that issue.
5. Prefer initializing in the class directly instead of writing a constructor.

   ```
   class BinTree{
       tree_node *root = nullptr;
   }
   ```

   That way you can also leave out the constructor.
6. I dislike the name `Search`. The return value tells me if it searched or not? I would prefer `contains` so that the return value fits to the name.
7. Your `BinTree` leaks memory. It creates `tree_node`s with `new` but doesn't `delete` them unless you manually call `Remove` for every single item. You have 2 options here: Insert a destructor that deletes all the nodes or just make `root`, `right` and `left` `unique_ptr`s, which will delete the nodes automatically. If you go the `unique_ptr` route you will have to change the implementation code a bit, because you cannot copy a `unique_ptr` (then it wouldn't be unique anymore) and instead `std::move` or `std::swap` them.
8. Your `BinTree` can be copied but the copy does the wrong thing. Instead of a copy I get 2 trees using the same nodes (because it just makes a copy of the `root` pointer). If I change one tree the other also changes. Instead you should write your own copy constructor that deep-copies the nodes. Same goes for the assignment operator. Also your `BinTree` would benefit from moving, so you should add a move-constructor and move-assignment, too.
9. `Search` prints stuff. As a user of your class I don't want that. Or at least let me specify an `std::ostream` where you should print it to.
10. `Search` should be a `const` function. Right now I cannot search for a value in a `const BinTree tree;`, but I should be able to.
11. In `Search` you keep the `parent`, but it is not used for anything. You could simplify that function to something like this:

    ```
    bool BinTree::Search(int d) const
    {
        const tree_node* curr = root;
        while (curr != nullptr)
        {
            if (curr->data == d)
                return true;
            if (d > curr->data)
                curr = curr->right;
            else
                curr = curr->left;
            //shorter, but lacks in readability:
            // curr = d > curr->data ? curr->right : curr->left;
        }
        return false;
    }
    ```
12. Your `BinTree` is not balanced. If I insert numbers from 1 to 1000 I effectively get an inefficient linked list.
13. `Remove` is indeed a bit tricky. I would just replace the deleted node with the left node and insert the right node into the left node.
14. You could trivially replace `int` with `T` and put `template <class T>` above your tree to make it not only work with `int`s, but with any data type. In that case you should make 2 versions of functions that now take an `int`: One that takes a `const T &` and one that takes a `T &&` that is then perfect forwarded.

There are good reasons why existing binary trees are so complicated. If you want lots of performance with lots of flexibility in lots of cases it costs you a lot of effort implementing the tree. Or you just use `std::set` and don't worry about it.